# ajax apache 503 despues de 60 segundos

Tags: php, timeout

Al realizar una petición ajax desde javascript hacia mi servidor, siempre despues de 60 segundos retorna código http 503. Lo otro raro es que el script en el servidor termina satisfactoriamente porque después reviso y hace todo lo que debía hacer, pero al recibir 503 no puedo mostrarle el resultado correcto al cliente.

En mi servidor uso Apache, php, php-fpm.

El script tarda porque realiza una petición a una api de un tercero y envía dos correos. Además que hace varias peticiones y escrituras en base de datos.

Agregué la siguiente línea al script y sigo con el problema

```
set_time_limit(180);
```

Nota: el script funciona bien en el servidor de prueba pero no en el de producción.

**Actualización**

La porción de código php que se ejecuta es la siguiente:

```
$productos = $cart->getProducts();

$this->data['CodigoCompra'] = $cart->id;
$this->data['FechaCompra'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this->data['FechaEntrega'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this->data['MontoTotal'] = $cart->getOrderTotal();
$this->data['productos'] = array();

foreach ($productos as $producto) {
    $p = array(
        "TipoCodigoProducto" => "SKU",
        "CodigoProducto" => $producto['reference'],
        "NombreProducto" => $producto['name'],
        "CantidadProducto" => $producto['cart_quantity'],
        "PrecioUnitario" => $producto['price'],
        "Informacion" => "",
    );
    array_push($this->data['productos'], $p);
}

if (empty($this->data['productos'])) {
    $oc->estado = MercadoPublicoOC::$ESTADOS[2];
    $oc->save(true);
    $this->ajaxDie(Tools::jsonEncode(array("error" => array("Sin productos asociados. Por favor verifique su carrito de compras"))));
}

$address = new Address((int)$cart->id_address_delivery);

if (!$usuario_mp->findRut($address->rut_cliente)) {
    $oc->estado = MercadoPublicoOC::$ESTADOS[2];
    $oc->save(true);
    $this->ajaxDie(Tools::jsonEncode(array("error" => array("Rut no encontrado"))));
}

$state = new State($address->id_state);

$this->data['RutComprador'] = $usuario_mp->Rut;
$this->data['CodigoUsuario'] = $usuario_mp->Codigo;
$this->data['CodigoUsuarioTienda'] = $cart->id_customer;
$this->data['DireccionDespacho'] = $address->address1 . '. ' . $address->comuna . '. ' . $state->name . '.';

set_time_limit(180);

$resultado = $this->CallAPI('POST', 'https://me-reservo-la-direccion/RegistroDeCompraQA/Registrar', $this->data);

if ($resultado['info']['http_code'] != 200) {
    $logger->logError('Respuesta HTTP de API de Mercado Publico invalido: ' . $resultado['info']['http_code']);
    $oc->estado = MercadoPublicoOC::$ESTADOS[2];
    $oc->save(true);
    $this->ajaxDie(Tools::jsonEncode(array("error" => array("Error generando Orden de Compra. Por favor, verifique en Mercado Público o intente más tarde."))));
}

$resultado2 = Tools::jsonDecode($resultado['response'], true);

if ($resultado2 == null) {
    $logger->logError('Resultado de API de Mercado Publico invalido: ' . $resultado['response']);
    $oc->estado = MercadoPublicoOC::$ESTADOS[2];
    $oc->save(true);
    $this->ajaxDie(Tools::jsonEncode(array("error" => array("Error generando Orden de Compra. Por favor, verifique en Mercado Público o intente más tarde."))));
}

$oc->id_cart = $cart->id;
$oc->estado = MercadoPublicoOC::$ESTADOS[1];
$oc->FechaRespuesta = $resultado2['FechaRespuesta'];
$oc->Respuesta = $resultado2['Respuesta'];
$oc->CodigoRespuesta = $resultado2['CodigoRespuesta'];
$oc->Url = $resultado2['Url'];

$oc->save(true);

if ($resultado2['CodigoRespuesta'] != 1) {
    $logger->logError('Codigo de respuesta no satisfactorio: ' . $resultado['response']);
    $oc->estado = MercadoPublicoOC::$ESTADOS[2];
    $oc->save(true);
    $this->ajaxDie(Tools::jsonEncode(array("error" => array("Error generando Orden de Compra.".PHP_EOL.$resultado2["Respuesta"].PHP_EOL."Por favor, verifique en Mercado Público o intente más tarde."))));
}

$customer = new Customer($cart->id_customer);

if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($customer))
    $this->redireccionar((new Link)->getPageLink('order&step=1'));

$currency = Context::getContext()->currency;
$total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH);

$this->module->validateOrder((int)$cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_OUTOFSTOCK_UNPAID'), $total, $this->module->displayName, NULL, NULL, (int)$currency->id, false, $customer->secure_key);
$this->redireccionar((new Link)->getPageLink('order-confirmation&id_cart='.(int)$cart->id.'&id_module='.(int)$this->module->id.'&id_order='.$this->module->currentOrder.'&key='.$customer->secure_key));
```

Uso prestashop

Comment: Entonces, hay algunas veces que tu script tarda menos de 60 segundos? Que pasa en esos casos? O siempre tarda mas de 60 segundos?

Comment: Necesitamos mas información para poder ayudarte, el codigo es tuyo puedes agregarlo a la pregunta

Comment: Siempre tarda más de 60 segundos @Kenny

Comment: Es un código un poco largo y complejo que tal vez termine confundiendo más @jasilva

Comment: Pero sin el codigo, no podemos tener idea de que este pasando, incluso si el error no se deba al codigo y este en alguna configuración del apache. Siempre puedes guiarte con esta guia https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve si crees que el codigo es muy largo y complejo solo agrega la parte que creas crucial para que podamos entender el problema

Comment: Recién volví a probar en el servidor de desarrollo y tarda 72 segundos. La única diferencia que observo en los servidores es que en el de desarrollo no uso php-fpm y en el de producción si @Kenny

Comment: Enmy, @jasilva tiene un buen punto. Yo me inclino mas por alguna configuracion de apache en tu servidor de producción, ya que segun dices en el de pruebas funcionaba bien. La w3 dice que cuando un servidor no esta disponible se deberia responder con este error inmediatamente, no creo que el tiempo sea tan importante, este es el [enlace](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). Es posible que algo asi este configurado en el servidor de produccion? Tienes acceso a esa informacion?

Comment: Seguramente el problema es de tu servidor, posiblemente esto te ayude [Error 503 service unavailable y como solucionarlo optimizando php-fpm](http://blogdavidrodriguez.piensaennaranja.com/2016/11/23/error-503-service-unavailable-y-como-solucionarlo-optimizando-php-fpm/)

Comment: Si tengo full acceso. Desde que instalé, lo único que agregué fueron virtualhosts. Revisé el php.ini, php-fpm, http.conf y no encuentro nada. Encontré esto [https://serverfault.com/questions/717481/how-can-i-fix-recurring-php-503-errors-on-my-apache-mod-proxy-fcgi-php-fpm-serve] y veo que en la configuracion de apache tengo un archivo php.conf con  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000" y en el de desarrollo tengo SetHandler application/x-httpd-php Tendrá esto algo que ver?

Comment: El SetHandle de apache indica quien va a tratar los diferentes ficheros SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000" deriva a php-fpm y SetHandler application/x-httpd-php deriva en el php que tenga en local. EL problema con php-fpm es en la configurción del soket el timeout es diferente que el del tiempo de ejecución. Pon la configuración del php-fpm y lo solucionamos

Answer (score 1):

esto es devido al tiempo de ejecucion limite que tiene php en `php.ini`, en realidad deberias modificar la directiva `max_execution_time` y `max_input_time`, estos parametros son los que en realidad tienen que ver con el tiempo qu puede durar ejecutandose un script en php, en la imagen siguiente te muestro las directivas que deberias manipular para facilitar la ejecucion de tu script php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]